# Integral problem with gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{2k+a}(x)\sin^{a}(x)dx=\frac{\Gamma(k+\frac{a+1}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+a+1)}.$$ How can I show this equality?

Comment: Your good old [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure as to the nature of the question itself, since if one assumes the $\beta(m,n)=2\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2m-1}(x)\cos^{2n-1}(x)\mathrm{d}x$, well the questions pretty much rendered ansered, since we have .However, if not then the above comment should help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's apply the following substitution $ \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}y&=\sin^{2}{x}\\ \mathrm{d}y&=2\cos{x}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\end{aligned}\right. $, we have : \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos^{2k+a}{x}\sin^{a}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left(1-\sin^{2}{x}\right)^{k+\frac{a+1}{2}-1}\left(\sin^{2}{x}\right)^{\frac{a+1}{2}-1}2\cos{x}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)^{k+\frac{a+1}{2}-1}y^{\frac{a+1}{2}-1}\,\mathrm{d}y}\\ &=\frac{1}{2}\beta\left(k+\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{a+1}{2}\right)\\ &=\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{a+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(k+a+1\right)}\end{aligned}